# Issue with Spark Job: Unable to run "python3"

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to run a Spark job that involves Python code on my local machine. However, I encountered the following error message in the logs:

```
23/07/20 21:24:03 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
23/07/20 21:24:04 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1140)
    ...
```

It seems that Spark is unable to find the "python3" executable on my system, which is causing the job to fail. I have verified that Python 3 is installed on my machine.

Here are some additional details about my setup:

```
Operating System: Windows 11 Pro
Spark Version: 3.3.2
Python Version: 3.10.11
```

I have checked my PATH variable, and "python3" is correctly added to it. I am unsure why Spark is still unable to find the Python executable.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue before or has any idea what might be causing this problem?

Comment: Does the Spark job run as your user account, or as a different account?

Comment: I have installed it on my personal machine and I am running it as the same user.

Comment: Modify the Spark job so that it prints the PATH, and compare that to your usual PATH.  They must be different.

Comment: In general, don't depend on your OS path to be the source of truth. Set environment variable `PYSPARK_PYTHON` to override this

Comment: I created the variable as indicated PYSPARK_PYTHON and set the path to the Python executable, and now it's running.. thank you very much!